# Importing json files in models with field definition using Django admin

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to import json data files by parsing into Django data models.

I have defined a table with the "Entidad" where the json file is uploaded with the data.

Through the actions of Django in admin I intend to upload the file, for example "Articles", launch the action, load the json and parse or match each field by importing the data into the models.

```
class Entidad(TimeStampedModel):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to="importaciones/entidades/", help_text="Fichero formato *.json")
```

Another "Relacion" table where the "origen" field (in the json) "destino" field of the model is indicated:

```
class Relacion(TimeStampedModel):
   entidad = models.ForeignKey("importaciones.Entidad", related_name="relaciones", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   origen = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Nombre del campo de la columna del fichero.")
   destino = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Nombre del campo de la base de datos.")
   modelo = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Nombre tabla de datos.")
```

The admin TabularInline:

```
class RelacionInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Relacion


class EntidadAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [
    RelacionInline,
   ]
   actions = ['importar_datos',]


def importar_datos(self, request, queryset):
    for entidad in queryset:
        with open(entidad.archivo.path) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            importa(data, entidad.relaciones)

    self.message_user(request, "Se ha importado xxx")


importar_datos.short_description = "Importar datos seleccionado(s)"

admin.site.register(Entidad, EntidadAdmin)
```

Example of the json file. It should be noted that there are related tables:

```
{
 "root": {
 "Products": [
  {
    "supplierCode": "34523",
    "date": "2019-04-13",
    "Product": [
      {
        "id": "789874",
        "References": {
          "Reference": [
            {
              "RefType": "GENERICO",
              "RefCode": "9879879787"
            },
            {
              "RefType": "EAN_UMV",
              "RefCode": "8000115115115"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Features": {
          "Feature": [
            {
              "FeatureCode": "1",
              "FeatureName": "Marca",
              "ValueCode": "402",
              "Value": "Nike"
            },
            {
              "FeatureCode": "2",
              "FeatureName": "Tipo",
              "ValueCode": "63",
              "Value": "Trail"
            },
            {
              "FeatureCode": "369",
              "FeatureName": "Estuche",
              "ValueCode": "15",
              "Value": "Carton"
            },
            {
              "FeatureCode": "63",
              "FeatureName": "Forma",
              "ValueCode": "23",
              "Value": "Hexagonal"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
     ]
     }
    ]
   }
  }
```

Recursion through the file with the intention of relating each field to then import the values into the model, but I do not know if it can be done, for now I think not:

```
def importar(obj, key, relaciones):
   arr = []
   diccionario = None
   valores = {}
   lista = ""
   diccionario = ""

   def extract(obj, arr):
      lista = ""
      diccionario = ""
      id = ""
      i = 0
      if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if k == "id":
                if id != k and id != None:
                    id = v
                    #print("cambio articulo ---",k, v)


            if isinstance(v, dict):
                #print("dict", k)
                diccionario = k
                extract(v, arr)

            if isinstance(v, list):
                lista = k
                extract(v, arr)


            elemento = relaciones.filter(origen=k).first()
            if elemento:
                valores[elemento.modelo + "." + elemento.destino] = v + " en: " + key


    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            extract(item, arr)
    return arr

results = extract(obj, arr)
return valores
```

I see that in this way I will not get it, any suggestions?